# how to set pagination last-page ui-bootstrap in the controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

how can i force the last page in pagination ui-bootstrap after running a function in the controller ?

my idea is to create a new element and show it once is created by setting the pagination in the last page, like this.

```
// create new product 
$scope.createElement = function(){
    $scope.crear = "2";

    // fields in key-value pairs
    $http.post('procesos/administradorcontroler.php', {
            'element' : $scope.banco,
            'action' : $scope.crear
        }
    ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {



        // refresh the list
        $scope.getAll();

       //go to last element created
       $scope.goLastPage();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a $scope.currentPage value in your controller than bind it to the ngModel attribute on the pagination directive as explained in the docs [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination)  It contains an example of what you are trying to do except you would need to set the ngModel value in your controller in the $http success function.

As per you comment below, the documents list the num-pages as a read only attribute, so

```
<pagination num-pages="numPages"></pagination>
```

will give you the number of pages rendered in the pagination, then you could do:

```
$scope.currentPage = $scope.numPages.
```

You may need to wrap that in a timeout to give the pagination directive time to render after setting the source in the $http response to make sure the num-pages will be accurate.

Comment: i understand, but how do i set $scope.currentPage = lastPage. i dont know how many pages does my pagination have after i created a item. so how do i track them.